# How to save an array of values with a POST request? (Wordpress API)

Tags: php, wordpress, api, post

I'm trying to work with the Wordpress API to update a user's information via a POST request. The information is stored in a custom JSON field, that I registered like so:

```
public function handle_user_info() {
    register_rest_field( 'user', 'personal_info', array(
        'get_callback' => array( $this, 'get_user_info_callback' ),
        'update_callback' => array( $this, 'post_user_info_callback' ),
        'schema' => null 
    ));        
}
```

Here's the GET callback:

```
public function get_user_info_callback( $user ) {  
    $userID = $user[ 'id' ]; 
    return array(
        'rcp_user_first' => get_user_meta( $userID, 'rcp_user_first', true ),
        'rcp_user_last' => get_user_meta( $userID, 'rcp_user_last', true ),
        'rcp_user_location' => get_user_meta( $userID, 'rcp_user_location', true ),
        'rcp_postal_address' => get_user_meta( $userID, 'rcp_postal_address', true ),
        'rcp_email' => get_userdata( $userID )->user_login
    );           
}
```

All of the above works fine. When I make a GET request, here's what is returned (shortened version):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "url": "http://example.com",
    "description": "",
    "slug": "admin",

    ...

    "personal_info": {
        "rcp_user_first": "John",
        "rcp_user_last": "Doe",
        "rcp_user_location": "EU",
        "rcp_postal_address": "101 Fake Street",
        "rcp_email": "admin@example.com"
    }

    ...

}
```

My problem is with the POST callback. I can't figure out how to write it to update the values in the `personal_info` field. My guess was that something like this would work:

```
public function post_user_info_callback( $value, $user, $fieldName ) { 

    return array(
        'rcp_user_first' => update_user_meta( 1, 'rcp_user_first', 'Mark' ),
        'rcp_user_last' => update_user_meta( 1, 'rcp_user_last', 'Smith' ),
        'rcp_user_location' => update_user_meta( 1, 'rcp_user_location', 'NON_EU' ),
        'rcp_postal_address' => update_user_meta( 1, 'rcp_postal_address', '202 Fantasy Street' )
    );           

}
```

However this does not work. By the way I'm only testing with Postman right now which is why I'm using static data, so 1 here stands for the user ID.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make sure you POST with the `personal_info` value so the callback will run.

For example add in the postman `personal_info[rcp_user_first]` with some value.
Now the callback will run and your static data will update.

And then you can write some function that update dynamic every user key and value pair.

```
public function post_user_info_callback( $value, $user, $fieldName ) {

    $defaultKeys = [
        'rcp_user_first' => '',
        'rcp_user_last' => '',
        'rcp_user_location' => '',
        'rcp_postal_address' => ''
    ];

    // filter the value so that we get only our specific keys that we want to update
    $valueArray = array_filter( array_merge( $defaultKeys, array_intersect_key( $value, $defaultKeys ) ) );

    $updateArray = [];
    foreach($valueArray as $key=>$val) {

        // Here you can add another validation for values.
        $updateArray[$key] = update_user_meta($user->ID, $key, $val);
    }

    return $updateArray;

}
```